# Prevent horizontal nav content from overflowing into padding

Tags: css

I'm putting a right arrow button on a horizontal navbar which, when clicked, will use JavaScript to scroll to the end of the menu if the content overflows. This arrow is in a div fixed onto the right side of the navbar, and currently obscures the end of the last link. I thought that adding a bit of padding to the nav container would solve the problem but it doesn't, the link just overflows into the padding.

[image]

And here's the link with the container's padding highlighted, where I have given `.Dashboard__sub-header__menu` a right padding of 60px:

[image]

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6byb56r/) to try and replicate the problem.

```js
function buildHorizontalScrollArrow() {
  var el = jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'horizontal-scroll-arrow-container'
  })
  
  var el2 = jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'horizontal-scroll-arrow',
    text: '>'
  })
  
  return $(element).append(el2);
}

function addHorizontalScrollArrow(element) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0];
  var arrowExists;
  
  if($('.horizontal-scroll-arrow').length) {
    arrowExists = true;
  } else {
    arrowExists = false;
  }
  
  if(el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
    if(arrowExists == false) {
      $(el).append(buildHorizontalScrollArrow())
    }
  } else {
    if(arrowExists == true) {
      $('.horizontal-scroll-arrow').remove();
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addHorizontalScrollArrow('Dashboard__sub-header__menu');
  
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    addHorizontalScrollArrow('Dashboard__sub-header__menu');
  })
  
  $(document).on('click', '.horizontal-scroll-arrow', function() {
    $('.Dashboard__sub-header__menu').scrollLeft(1200);
  })
});
```

```css
.Dashboard__sub-header__menu {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 90px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0 3em 0 3em;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
   overflow-x: auto;
   position: fixed;
   border: 0;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Dashboard__sub-header__menu li {
  padding: 0 1.4em;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Dashboard__sub-header__menu li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.horizontal-scroll-arrow-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 9px; /* This is just for the Fiddle */
}

.horizontal-scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="Dashboard__sub-header__menu Active">
  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Institutions</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Investigators</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Site Contacts</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Labs</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">IRBs/IECs</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Regulatory/Competent Authorities</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Organizations</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav-link">
    <a href="#">Organization Contacts</a>
  </li>

  <div class="horizontal-scroll-arrow-container">
    <div class="horizontal-scroll-arrow">&gt;</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see any padding right defined on `.Dashboard__sub-header__menu`

Comment: @Red I did that in Chrome inspector in order to take the second screenshot and demonstrate that it doesn't work

Comment: @Obsidian thanks, corrected.

Comment: Well, you should post a fiddle where the problem is reproduced. I don't see the error in the current fiddle. Without it, we are most likely not able to help you.

Comment: @Red Ok I added a fiddle that I think just about replicates the problem, let me know what you think.

Comment: Can't see a fiddle..

Comment: @paddyfields Red's edit seemed to remove it, I've put it back in now.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do it this way. Assuming I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

```css
section{
  position:relative;
  padding-right:15px;
}
.Dashboard__sub-header__menu {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0 0 0 3em;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.Dashboard__sub-header__menu li {
  padding: 0 1.4em;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.horizontal-scroll-arrow-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

.horizontal-scroll-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="horizontal-scroll-arrow-container">
    <div class="horizontal-scroll-arrow">&gt;</div>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="Dashboard__sub-header__menu Active">
    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Institutions</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Investigators</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Site Contacts</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Labs</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">IRBs/IECs</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Regulatory/Competent Authorities</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Organizations</a>
    </li>

    <li class="main-nav-link">
      <a href="#">Organization Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there's a couple of issues with this, such as section needs to be in a fixed position (should have mentioned that, apologies). I added a jsfiddle if you want to take a look.

Comment: So make it fixed! It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok I've tried playing around with this for a while but no matter what I do the link still goes into the padding! From what I understand you've put the class onto a ul element instead of the section (I don't know why that isn't currently there by the way, I didn't write this code), positioned the section relatively, and set the padding on the section. Did I miss anything?